# Fetch all CC emails - Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail gem within my rails app: https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail

I'm trying to retrieve all emails that have any recipients CC'd. Here is what I have:

```
gmail.inbox.search(gm: "cc:").each do |email|
```

This gives me back all emails. How do I get this to work?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to ask for every message that has a `cc`-header, sadly. What are you trying to achieve? I know that you can get every message the user himself is given a copy, by writing `cc:me`, but maybe that is not what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, it is impossible to run a search on cc without a parameter to it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?